# how to record all input and output of terminal including the changes to the file when editting a file using 'nano'

Tags: ubuntu

On Ubuntu, how do I record all input and output of the terminal, not just logging all commands but also record when you edit a file using `nano`, every change to the file should also be included.

I tried `script`, but it only contains the commands but does not include when you change a file.

Comment: Have you tried a version control system like `git`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/). There is the description on its website：

> ttyrec is a tty recorder. Recorded data can be played back with the included ttyplay command. ttyrec is just a derivative of script command for recording timing information with microsecond accuracy as well. It can record emacs -nw, vi, lynx, or any programs running on tty.

I can use it to record vi/vim output. So it may be useful for you.

To record a terminal, just execute

```
ttyrec
```

exit just type:

```
exit
```

or

```
Ctrl+D
```

To replay your input and output, execute:

```
ttyplay ttyrecord
```